# Uniform convergence on compact sets and convergence on $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of real functions such that :

1. $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R},\mu)$, for some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. For any compact set $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ $f_{n}|_K$ converge uniformly on $K$ to a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
3. $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},\mu)$.

Can I deduce that $f_n \stackrel{L^1(\mu)}{\longrightarrow} f$ ?

Comment: What about $f=0$ and $f_n = 1_{[n,n+1)}/\mu([n,n+1))$, where I assume that the measure of each of the sets $[n,n+1)$ is positive.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the reasoning will be ok even if we take the closed set $[n,n+1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result holds iff $\mu(K)=1$ for some compact $K.$

Proof: Suppose the result holds. Assume, to reach a contradiction, that $\mu(K)<1$ for all compact $K.$ It follows that there are integers $0<m_1<m_2<\cdots $ such that $\mu(\{x:m_n<|x|<m_{n+1}\}) >0$ for all $n.$ Then, as suggested in the comments, we can define

$$f_n=\frac{1}{\mu(\{x:m_n<|x|<m_{n+1}\}}\chi_{\{x:m_n<|x|<m_{n+1}\}}.$$

Note that $\int f_n\,d\mu =1$ for all $n.$We then have your conditions met, with $f=0,$ but $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in $L^1.$ That's a contradiciton, and therefore $m(K)=1$ for some compact $K.$

The other directions is simple to prove, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: Isn't that the same as saying that $\mu$ is compactly supported?

Comment: @LL3.14  Yes it is.